# How to fix the variables not moving when doing optimization?

Tags: matlab

Suppose I have a function which has, say 5 inputs: say `f(z,t1,t2,t3,t4)`. I want to do optimization using `lsqnolin`, i.e. `min f(z,t1,t2,t3,t4)`. However, I have the following request:

User can determine which variables `t1,t2,t3,t4` to be optimized. When user input 3 to the program, it means that I need to fix `t4` while `z,t1,t2,t3` can be changed to get the minimum value. If user input 2 to the program, it means that I need to fix `t3,t4` while `z,t1,t2` can be changed to get the minimum value.

I understand I can use conditional statement, but in my program, the function can have 20 inputs or even more. What's more, my program accept input `[z,t1,t2,t3,t4]` at the same time. What I find online require optimization of variables `[z,t1,t2,t3,t4]` at the same time, but not a particular variable to be fixed.

Comment: If your function accepts a single 5 element vector as the input then for the variables that need to be fixed you can set `lb(i) = ub(i) = const` which will have the effect of constraining the variable to a fixed value. If it accepts 5 different inputs then just define a function handle e.g. `newFunc = @(z,t1,t2,t3)f(z,t1,t2,t3,5)` (t4 = 5) and do the optimization on the new function. And you will need to have some conditional for handling user input.

Comment: In this case, I still need to use conditional statement, am I right?

Comment: So which of these two signatures do you have ? Five separate inputs or a single 5 element input ? You need conditionals to handle user input in both, if you can elaborate all your user inputs, may be we can come up with some trick to avoid conditionals